# Symbolicate Output - Understanding the error

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, symbolicate, symbolicatecrash

My App is crashing a "**14**". I have a business object called "**ClientDetail**" but this object has no Bools. What is it referring to? There is also no line 784, I am guessing the + 784 is then not a line number reference?

```
13  HappyApp 0x008b907c handle_signal_exception (exceptions-arm.c:532)
14  HappyApp 0x003259c8 General_ProjectViewController__ctor_General_ClientDetail_bool + 784
15  HappyApp 0x00323f80 General_ClientViewController_DoTap_General_ClientDetail + 224
16  HappyApp 0x0033c700 General_ClientViewController__Populatec__AnonStorey1__m__11 + 132
17  HappyApp 0x00009e14 MonoTouch_Dialog_StringElement_Selected_MonoTouch_Dialog_DialogViewController_MonoTouch_UIKit_UITableView_MonoTouch_Foundation_NSIndexPath + 200
```

In the ProjectViewController constructor I assign a local client the passed in "Client".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash is happening in General.ProjectViewController's constructor that has this signature:

ClientDetail (bool value)

The 784 references the offset from the start of the method in machine instructions.

Comment: Ah yes. And that Constructor is a MonoTouch.Dialog dialogview. You may have heard of it. An amazing system to create fast Table based UI for iPhones [grin]...